# Keras NN loss is 1

Tags: keras, neural-network

Getting started with simple NN but my loss remains one at each iteration.  Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong here.

This is from a Kaggle introductory course and my modified training set contains shop id, category id, item id, month and revenue.  I'm basically trying to predict revenue per shop per category for the following month.

I've scaled revenue and trained on a simple NN with 2 hidden layers; however, it doesn't seem like the training is working as the loss remains constant.  I haven't done anything with the labels (ie shop ids, category ids) but I would still think the loss would change on each iteration.

If you have some comments on coding practice, I would be interested as well.

Thanks.

```
X_train = grouped_train.drop('revenue', axis=1)
y_train = grouped_train['revenue']

print('X & y trains')
print(X_train.head())
print(y_train.head())

scaler = StandardScaler()
y_train = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(y_train.values.reshape(-1,1)))

print('Scaled y train')
print(y_train.head())

keras.backend.clear_session()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.summary()

print('Compile & fit')
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='RMSprop')
model.fit(X_train, scaled_data, batch_size=128, epochs=13)

predictions = pd.DataFrame(model.predict(test))

print('Scaled predictions')
print(predictions.head())

print('Unscaled predictions')
print(pd.DataFrame(scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)).head())
```

[IN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E32En.png)

[OUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D88nf.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text not as images.

Comment: @thushv89 ok added the code to the body of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using the wrong activation for the final layer.  You have a regression problem so the standard final activation layer should be activation = 'linear'

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

Edit:
Additionally model.fit is using 'scaled_data' shouldn't scaled_data be replaced with y_train

Comment: yeah that was it.  also does it matter if I pass a dataframe vs numpy array to Keras's fit function?

Comment: I believe Keras fit function handles any 'Array like' but I have not tested to know if there are performance differences, etc.